# Creating dataset from matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a dataset from a double matrix and cell array of labels.

I don't have access to the mat2dataset function so I'm trying to write something similar.

```
>> whos data feature_labels
  Name                Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes
  data                2x208             3328  double              
  feature_labels      1x208            50776  cell
```

In actual use the data will have ~2million rows and always be double format. The number of columns will range from 20 up to 2000, so doing something like;

```
>> D = dataset([],[],[],[],[],...[], 'VarNames', feature_labels);
```

isn't really feasible.

Any suggestions?

edit:

Currently using a for loop and horzcat to concatenate new dataset columns on each loop. I don't see a way to pre-allocate the dataset size is this way so I imagine performance will chug with the larger datasets though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a struct? I use these all the time in MATLAB for database things. I know it works absolutely fantastic for up to 20,000 elements with about 15 fields each, so I think it would still work just as well as anything else for 2 million items with 2 fields.

Alternatively, can't you just put it in a cell array?

```
DataBase{rowNum,1}=dataVector(rowNum,:);
DataBase{rowNum,2}=label{rowNum};
```

To preallocate a struct or cell, its relatively easy, with a struct, once you make your first one to initialize the fields, just say `Struct(2000000).fieldName =[]`

TO preallocate your cell array, just do

```
DataBase={[]}
DataBase{2000000,2}=[]
```

This preallocates all of it and fills it with empty values.

Comment: It'll be 2 million items with 20-2000 named fields, so struct(2000000).field1 = [] won't do for preallocating as I'd have to do it for each. I wanted to use dataset because it makes selecting rows and named fields quite easy but I may just go with columns of csv files. :)

Comment: What variables do you have? With your 20 to 2000 named fields, what are those?? It sounds like you just have a bunch of matrices..

Comment: And then text labels to go along with those? You cam also embed structs you know, I don't know how familiar you are with structs, but I am still pretty sure those or a cell array will work for you